# java. help accessing array that is inside a method from another method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

In this I am attempting to get the `salutations()` method to output the array created in the `initialize()` method.

The error I receive just tells me to create a local variable for the array when i need it to be inside the other method.

```
public void initialize() {
String[] salutations = new String[]{"greetings", "hello", "good afternoon"};
String[] verses = new String[]{"we hope you are having a good Christmas", "we wish you a merry x-mas", "we wish you a good new year"};
String[] closing = new String[]{"", "b", "c"};
}
public  void salutations(){
    int i=1;
     String x;
    x=(String)Array.get(salutations, i);
     System.out.println(+x+" ");
  }
```

Comment: Store it in a field in your class, or pass it as argument to your method

Comment: Learn about scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public String salutations(int i){
     String x = salutations[i].toString;
     return x + " ";
  }
```

To call a method and have it return a value. You must declare the datatype. In this case it's a string.

> public String

To pass in a value to a method you must declare the data type and give it a variable name

> salutations(int i)

Together it looks like:

```
public String salutations(int i)
```

Now you can call the method by passing in an int.

```
System.out.println(salutations(1) + "Bob")
```

Answer (score 0):

Create fields for each `String[]` and refer to them in other methods:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String[] salutations;
    private String[] verses;
    private String[] closing;

    public void initialize() {
        salutations = new String[]{"greetings", "hello", "good afternoon"};
        verses = new String[]{"we hope you are having a good Christmas", "we wish you a merry x-mas", "we wish you a good new year"};
        closing = new String[]{"", "b", "c"};
    }

    public void salutations() {
        int i = 1;
        String x;
        x = salutations[i];
        System.out.println(x + " ");
    }
}
```

Other minor syntax errors corrected.